# sum over primes and its powers

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

are there examples in number theory where the series

$$ \sum_{p} \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}f(p^{m}) $$ or

$$ \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}f(q^{m}) $$ for fixed prime 'q' appear ??

i believe they may be relate to p-adic integrals $$ \int_{Q_{p}}f(x)dx $$

Comment: Could you add what $f$ and $Q_p$ are?

Comment: I'd guess that by $\int_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ he means an integral over the $p$-adic numbers.